# behind the presentingViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipresentationcontroller

I'm trying to do custom transitioning for modal view presentation using `UIPresentationController`, like below.

[image]

I scaled my presenting view like the following (inside `func presentingTransitionWillBegin()`):

```
self.presentingViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
```

However, background of the `presentingView` is always **black**, and I can't find the right place to change the color.

I tried adding a white-colored view to the `containerView` and then add `self.presentingViewController.view` as its subview:

```
someView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
containerView.addSubview(someView)
someview.addSubview(self.presentingViewController.view)
```

well, it worked somehow. but obviously it crashes after I dismiss the modal view. and I can't find where to place back this `self.presentingViewController.view` when dismiss transition ends!

Ultimately, I want to achieve something like below:

[image]

Comment: why did you add self.presentingViewController.view as subview while present ?

Comment: @KKRocks because I need the background to be white while `presentingView` scales down as it presents.

Comment: you can set this background in that class instead of while presenting .

Comment: Don't dismiss the View Controlller , Remove  all `SubView` of `someView`

Comment: @KKRocks this class is a subClass of `UIPresentationController` and what property do you suggest to change? `self.backgroundColor` or `self.view` does not exists...

Comment: can you present that controller using  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Dhiru then everything will go black when I dismiss the presented modal view at some point.

Comment: put code that show how to present this view .